# great grandather Luigi Raimondi and Sylvia Fiorentini in Brasil 1900

Tags: 1900s-decade, italy, brazil

Sylvia Fiorentini was born in Italy. Her father went to Brasil for a three years contract as an architect or engineer? in the building of theatres in Brasil 1900s. Unable to trace him.

.
 Sylvia's sister married a german and Sylvia stayed to accompany until her confinement. Sylvia in the meantime married Luigi Raimondi and remained in Brasil. Her parents returned to Italy.

I've been unable to find her father's name
His work details
Sister's name or whereabouts after her confinement in Brasil.

I believe Sylvia’s family came from Ferrara, north of Rome

Comment: Do you know when Sylvia was born in Italy?  When and where did Sylvia marry Luigi in Brazil?  Have you found a marriage record/certificate that may mention her father's name?

Answer (score 2):

The obvious record you need to get to begin with is the marriage of Sylvia and Luigi in Brasil. There may be two possible sources - church records and civil records.

Where and how to find them depends on the exact location and time. Some records are available at www.familysearch.org but a great number of them are **not name indexed** - this means that even if you don't get any hits searching from the top page, but if you know the location and approximate date of marriage you may still be able to find it.

A marriage may give you Sylvia's parents names. Moreover, there's a good chance her sister or brother in law were witnesses, which would make finding those records much easier.

There is further information on both [civil registration](https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/Brazil_Civil_Registration) and [church records](https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/Brazil_Church_Records) in Brasil.